# Overwrite Vista with XP Professional and then reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have Vista on a laptop. I have tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside from the official disk. This has partly worked in that I can now surf much faster with Ubuntu which I like. Unfortunately I can get no sound on things like YouTube, and none of my Windows programs will load up.

I guess that this could be down to Vista inhibiting Ubuntu. Also I cannot get Vista to start at all. Please help me. I need to temporarily delete Ubuntu. I can then overwrite my corrupt Vista with XP Professional and then reinstall Ubuntu for the surfing experience and to use the open source utilities.

Answers in plain language for a Ubuntu newbie.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows programs will not natively run in Ubuntu because Ubuntu is based on Linux, and Windows is based on DOS. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) They're two *very* different environments.

One way to run Windows programs in Ubuntu is by using `wine`, but even that is a bit unstable.

Did you use `wubi` to install Ubuntu inside the Windows partition? If so, back up all your files in Ubuntu first, then boot from the XP disc, then opt to erase the Vista partition.

Or did you install Ubuntu on a different partition? If so, no need to delete Ubuntu, just directly boot from the XP disk and erase the Vista partition for installation!

What sound hardware do you have (e.g. sound card, speakers, etc.)? Perhaps you just need some drivers.